# Tensorflow Received a label value of 9 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5) when using transfer learning

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'am trying learn model with mnist digits dataset to recognize numbers 0-4 and next using transfer learning to recognize numbers 5-9. First part run without problem but when I'am trying use transfer learning for 5-9 digits i got error

> Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
> Received a label value of 9 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).  Label values: 7 8 9 9 6 6 9 9 5 6 6 6 7 6 8 8 5 9 7 5 6 8 5 5 6 9 5 8 6 7 8 5
> [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_539246]

This is first part with working code and structure

```
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[784]))
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation="elu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation="elu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation="elu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation="elu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation="elu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax", kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform"))
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
early_stopping_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
checkpoint_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("mnist_number_model_bn_dp.h5", save_best_only=True)
history = model.fit(train_0_4_X, train_0_4_y, epochs=100, validation_data=(test_0_4_X, test_0_4_y), callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb])
```

This is the second part where error occurs. Last layer is replace with new softmax and remaining layers are freeze.

```
model_A = tf.keras.models.load_model("mnist_number_model_bn_dp.h5")
model_B_on_A = tf.keras.models.Sequential(model_A.layers[:-1])
model_B_on_A.add(layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax", kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform"))

for layer in model_B_on_A.layers[:-1]:
    layer.trainable = False

model_B_on_A.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
early_stopping_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
checkpoint_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("mnist_number_model_bn_dp.h5", save_best_only=True)
history = model_B_on_A.fit(train_5_9_X, train_5_9_y, epochs=100, validation_data=(test_5_9_X, test_5_9_y), callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb])
```

Comment: Integer labels always go from 0 to C - 1, with C the number of classes.

Comment: When I change integer value to string in labels I got error "ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible" when I am trying train first model again.

Comment: try using `train_5_9_y-5` and same for all the Y in the fit call, you will see what magic happens